# HTML5 input type number reformats long number

Tags: html

I have an application whereby a user has to input a minimum of 15 digits in a number type textbox.

If a user enters a longer number, sometimes >= 19 digits, and then either uses the arrows on the right or the arrow keys on their keyboard, it autoformats the number to a float with `e+` at the end which, obviously, isn't ideal.

```html
<input min="0" type="number" value="7897894561234567898">
```

What's the best way to either remove or counteract this behaviour? Is there anything to be done, or will I have to use a text type input? (I'd rather not).

Comment: I see the `e+` in Chrome, but in FF I can't even use the arrows to change the number, which FF also converts to `7897894561234570000`

Comment: Do you really need the up/down arrows?

Comment: @Josh Lee, no, however it happens also when the user presses the up/down arrows on the keyboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML5 `<input type=number>` specifically uses the same Number type as JavaScript. The [maximum integer value before precision is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) is 9007199254740991, which has 16 digits.

You can't handle larger integers than that as a Number in JavaScript, you have to treat it as a string.

You should use `<input type=text>`, along with a `pattern` attribute for validation, and an `inputmode` attribute for touchscreens. The default validation message is not useful, so the `'invalid'` event should also be handled.

(Just kidding, `inputmode` isn't supported anywhere. You should use `<input type=tel>` to show a numeric keyboard on touchscreen devices.)

```html
<form>
  <input name=num type=tel
         required pattern="\d+"
         oninvalid="setCustomValidity('A number is required')"
         oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

There's a note in the spec about credit card numbers:

> The `type=number` state is not appropriate for input that happens to only consist of numbers but isn't strictly speaking a number. For example, it would be inappropriate for credit card numbers or US postal codes. A simple way of determining whether to use type=number is to consider whether it would make sense for the input control to have a spinbox interface (e.g. with "up" and "down" arrows).

See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)